# How does the CheckBox obtain it's respective drawables?

Tags: android, checkbox, coding-style

The CheckBox class extends the CompoundButton, but add nothing to it. But some how it obtains it's respective look. I found some declarations in Android sources, but wonder how they are mapped to CheckBox class?

```
public class CheckBox extends CompoundButton {
    public CheckBox(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, com.android.internal.R.attr.checkboxStyle);
    }

    public CheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
}
```

Styles

```
<style name="Theme">
    <item name="checkboxStyle">@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_check_label_background</item>
    <item name="android:button">@android:drawable/btn_check</item>
</style>
```

**EDIT:**

Probably I was not clear... I understand how the drawable assigned to Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox style, but how this style assigned to CheckBox class? I see the ".CheckBox" in the style name, but is this naming convention really what makes the trick? If so, what are the rules? If I derive MyCheckBox from CompoundButton, can I just define the Widget.CompoundButton.MyCheckBox style and it will work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's your answer: `<item name="android:button">@android:drawable/btn_check</item>`

A drawable can have multiple states (whether or not the element is focused, pressed, etc), and that's where the different states of the checkbox are.

EDIT: After you revised your question, I see that you're looking for something different. Again, it's all in what you posted:

```
<style name="Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
```

This is the style.

```
<item name="checkboxStyle">@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox</item>
```

The main theme (android.internal.R.attr) has an attribute "checkboxStyle" that points to this style.

```
public CheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, com.android.internal.R.attr.checkboxStyle);
}
```

The constructor assigns that attribute to the view. And that's it.

Comment: Oh.. Indeed, I have overlooked the checkboxStyle. TY!

Answer (score 1):

Right here

```
<item name="android:button">@android:drawable/btn_check</item>
```